# @EnableAutoConfiguration - excludeName

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I am working on a Springboot application, where a server startup (Tomcat) initializes bunch of classes. There are some unwanted ones being initialized and I am trying to improve the performance of startup so dont want to iniztialze these classes. I tried using @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation in my SpringBootServletInitializer with excludeName parameter as below :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(excludeName  = "com.foler.subfolder.ExampleClass")
```

I also tried with another parameter 
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ExampelClass.class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are some unwanted ones being initialized and I am trying to
>   improve the performance of startup so don't want to initialize these
>   classes.

Auto-configuration (using `@EnableAutoConfiguration`) is always applied after user-defined beans have been registered, look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.8.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html) from the API here on the same point.

So, you should actually use `@ComponentScan` **to filter the classes** as part of the scanning so that the container might speed up (as it will not create bean objects from excluded packages/classes during the container startup).

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.foler"}, 
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                           type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                           value = ExampelClass.class))
```

---

> Is there any way I can add two or more classes for value parameter?

`values` accepts the type `Class[]` array , so you can set the multiple classses as `value = {ExampelClass1.class, ExampelClass2.class}`

Comment: Thanks, I am getting this : An error occured while processing a @ComponentScan ANNOTATION type filter:  class com.folder.sublfolder.Example.class is not assignable to interface java.lang.annotation.Annotation.

Comment: `FilterType` should be `ASSIGNABLE_TYPE`

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway I can add two or more classes for value parameter. For example, value  = ExampleClass.class, AnotherClass.class

Comment: yes, `value = {ExampelClass1.class, ExampelClass2.class}`

Comment: Thank you. I have another class which is present in a jar file and I need to exclude the file. I tried including the jar package this way : basePackages = {"com.foler", "testjar.folder"}, but the file is not being excluded. Any other way I can  do it?

Comment: `@ComponentScan({"com.my.package.first","com.my.package.second"})`, don't specify jar names

Comment: dindt get you. Should I declare as {"com.folder.first", "com.testjar.second"}, where my first class ExampleClass1.class is in first package and the second one is in com.testjar(not jar name)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141385/discussion-between-user2296988-and-javaguy).

Comment: Please help javaguy